# Parsing json with SQL Server OpenJson

Tags: sql, sql-server, open-json

I am trying to parse the following json:

```
declare @json nvarchar(2048) = N'{
"brand": "BMW",
"year": 2019,
"price": 1234.6,
"colors": ["red","blue","black"]
}'
```

using:

```
select
    a.CarBrand,
    a.CarModel,
    a.CarPrice,
    b.color
from
openjson(@json)
with  
(
    CarBrand varchar(100) '$.brand',
    CarModel int '$.year',
    CarPrice money '$.price',
    colors nvarchar(max) as json
) as a
cross apply openjson(a.colors)
with
(
    [color] varchar(10)
) as b
```

but I keep receiving nulls for the color. I'm still trying to understand the openjson and cross apply syntax but I can't quite get this to work.

Current outcome:

```
CarBrand    CarModel    CarPrice    color
BMW         2019        1234.60     NULL
BMW         2019        1234.60     NULL
BMW         2019        1234.60     NULL
```

Desired outcome:

```
CarBrand    CarModel    CarPrice    color
BMW         2019        1234.60     red
BMW         2019        1234.60     blue
BMW         2019        1234.60     black
```

Comment: so if I have a single (non-nested array) I just need to tell it to extract each value via '$'? How simple!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use an explicit schema (the `WITH` clause), you need to define the path (`... [color] varchar(10) '$' ...` ) in the second `OPENSJON()` call:

```
select a.CarBrand, a.CarModel, a.CarPrice, b.color
from openjson(@json) with (
    CarBrand varchar(100) '$.brand',
    CarModel int '$.year',
    CarPrice money '$.price',
    colors nvarchar(max) as json
) as a
cross apply openjson(a.colors) with (
    [color] varchar(10) '$'
) as b
```

Answer (score 1):

`colors` is an array; it doesn't have a key called `color`. Just use `OPENJSON` with **no** `WITH` clause and return the `value` for your `colors` array:

```sql
DECLARE @json nvarchar(2048) = N'{
    "brand": "BMW",
    "year": 2019,
    "price": 1234.6,
    "colors": ["red","blue","black"]
}';


SELECT OJ.CarBrand,
       OJ.CarModel,
       OJ.CarPrice,
       C.value AS color
FROM OPENJSON(@json)
         WITH (CarBrand varchar(100) '$.brand',
               CarModel int '$.year',
               CarPrice money '$.price',
               colors nvarchar(MAX) AS JSON) OJ
     CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(OJ.colors) C;
```

Comment: Lets say ```"price"``` was also an array of 3 unique items. How could I handle exploding the price array alongside the colors array and maintain the order?

Comment: Sounds like you have a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) @Coldchain9 .